# How do I change the scroll behaviour of TDrawGrid

Tags: delphi

The TDrawGrid component has a standard way of determining how much to scroll when you scroll to the right and left for example.  I want the same behaviour as with a TScrollBox. The amount scrolled to the right and left is a lot less and you can control that. I was using a TScrollBox for this exact reason until I figured out that I can't have fixed Rows and Fixed Cols anymore because my ScrollBox determines the scrolling.

Is there a short way to do this without creating my own component?

Comment: Judging by the amount of calculation involved in TCustonGrid, no there's no short way to do this with or without creating a component.

Comment: This looks like it could provide me some usefull info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983858/how-to-create-a-custom-control-which-can-scroll-with-a-fixed-row-and-column?rq=1